# handling XML enum types in java

Tags: java, xml, enums, jax-ws

In Java I have a class with a property :

```
@XmlElement(name = "Ability")
protected String Ability;
```

Ability can be either Low, Medium or High.

Later on in the code some un-validated data needs to be assigned to Ability.

```
test.setAbility(pdf.get("Ability"));
```

Should I enum ability and how can I make it so that Ability only gets set if it is one of the enum types?

Answer (score 2):

Using an enum would be beneficial in your situation, you could use a mapper to convert the strings:

```
public static String mapAbilityEnum(String ability) {
    switch (ability) {
    case "LOW":
        return AbilityEnum.LOW;
    case "MEDIUM":
        return AbilityEnum.MEDIUM;
    case "HIGH":
        return AbilityEnum.HIGH;
    default:
        return foo; (whatever you want the default to be)
    }
}
```